Is there a package to search and insert an unicode character?
I would like to execute a command which then shows a searchable list of unicode characters. In that list I want to see the character and its name. I can filter that list by name. Then I can select a character and it gets inserted.

This question is similar to: Fast unicode symbol insertion?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There are several similar questions. Search here for C-x 8.

Just type C-x 8 <return> <tab>, which invokes the command insert-char and lists the corresponding completion items.
